# Angular Mentions - Save ID value of the selected users

Tags: angular, typescript

With the help of the angular mentions library, I implemented a textarea that allows me to mention several users.

Is there a way to save the ID of the selected users? If possible save them as an array of strings.

Example: I selected users Name 1, Name 2, Name 3 .... I want to be able to save the id and not the name. ["1", "2", "3"]

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xxez2r?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

**HTML**

```
 <div [mention]="items" class="form-control" contenteditable="true" style="border:1px lightgrey solid;min-height:88px" [mentionConfig]="{triggerChar:'@',labelKey:'name'}"></div>
```

**Component.ts**

```
 items: string[];
  constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userService.getUsers().subscribe(
      (val: any[]) =>{
        this.items = val;
      } 
    )
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- you should first use textarea instead of div so you can use [(ngModel)] to bind the selected user names

```
<textarea type="text" [mention]="items" 
 class="form-control" contenteditable="true" style="border:1px lightgrey solid;min-height:88px" [mentionConfig]="{triggerChar:'@',maxItems:10,labelKey:'name'}" [(ngModel)]="data"></textarea>
```

2-create variable data to bind all the text in the textarea

3-from the json data you can create the typescript classes represent the json properties to make it easy for data filtering

```
export interface Geo {
  lat: string;
  lng: string;
}

export interface Address {
  street: string;
  suite: string;
  city: string;
  zipcode: string;
  geo: Geo;
}

export interface Company {
  name: string;
  catchPhrase: string;
  bs: string;
}

export interface RootObject {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  username: string;
  email: string;
  address: Address;
  phone: string;
  website: string;
  company: Company;
}
```

4-use this save method to get all the selected name ids

```
 save() {
        let ids = this.data.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "").split("@").filter(t => t != "" && this.items.findIndex(u => u.name == t.trim()) > -1).map(name => this.items.find(s => s.name == name.trim()).id);
  }
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-js1jpt)

Comment: Your solution is almost perfect, however if you select more than one person, you will get the following error: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined. Can you solve it?

Comment: Sure , but I tested it using the demo link with more than one person and It works well , can you give me your test case ?

Comment: I put in the post the image of the error and my test.

Comment: Perfect , I'm checking now

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the *Mention* module works by binding only on a string value - thereby, you need to make the following changes by making use of the [`map`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/map) operator:

.ts

```
this.userService.getUsers().subscribe((val: any[]) => {
   // mapping each value to a string
   this.items = val.map((e: any) => String(e.id));
});
```

.html

```
<div 
   [mention]="items" class="form-control" 
   contenteditable="true" 
   style="border:1px lightgrey solid;min-height:88px" 
   [mentionConfig]="{triggerChar:'@',labelKey:'id'}">  // change made here
</div>
```

[Here's](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-abvvmw) a demo of the same.

Comment: Are you getting an error? I was able to get the *ids* in the console with the aobve answer..

Comment: Names don't appear where?

Comment: By changing this e.id by e.name the names appear but I can't get what I want. Visually in the dropdown I hold the names appear to me, but what I want to keep is the ID

Comment: Not worked too much on this component but can you apply `[mentionConfig]="{triggerChar:'@',labelKey:'id'` to a number?

Comment: With the ID it no longer appears the names. If you want you can try it on my stacklitz link in the post.  
You already posted a solution that he got the ID of all who were in the dropdown, I just want the ones I select. I think you've been too close

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but is there a way for labelkey ​​to be the name? I intend to display the name and not the ID. The ID, I just want to save the user associated with that comment in the database.

That is, I present the name but keep the ID value of that selected person.

Comment: Yeah, but then how is that different from your original post?!

Comment: This directive iterates on objects present in `[items]`, then there would be no point in mapping only the id's in that case..

Comment: ++ If you want to just save the id's, use another array and apply the map operator and store them there.

Comment: Already tried but couldn't :( yes I just want to save the ID of the chosen ones.
I will accept your answer for your effort and dedication

Comment: Probably using another library that has the selection event is easier fvi-angular-mentions

Answer (score 1):

I highly encourage you to use this library [fvi-angular-mentions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fvi-angular-mentions). In [fvi-angular-mentions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fvi-angular-mentions) you have the option to get the selected users.

The library you are using doesnt have any `eventEmitter` to get the selected user name.
It only has 3 event emitters:

```
@Output() serchTerm EventEmitter<string>-Event that is emitted whenever the search term changes. Can be used to trigger async search.
@Output() opened EventEmitter<void>-Event that is emitted when the mentions panel is opened.
@Output() closed EventEmitter<void>-Event that is emitted when the mentions panel is closed.
```

Which unfortunately doesnt work for you.

Comment: I think you're right, but using this same library, how can I get the selected user ID? Can you help me? Thank you !

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot do it in the library you are using. It's not a good thing to edit or going with hacky solution like editing a library. alot of things can go wrong there. As per my knowelage best thing for you to do is switch to suggested library. Would you mind making this correct answer. Had to go through alot of research find out this facts. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Mike can you update this as the answer? Thanks in advance